# Ошибка 401 Authorization Required nginx при входе в админ WordPress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Дали данные для входа на сайт. При попытке перейти на site.ru/wp-admin/ выдает эту ошибку:

```
Ошибка 401 Authorization Required nginx
```

Подскажите что делать чтобы войти наконец в админку. Есть еще доступ к FTP, вроде бы рабочий.

Comment: Попросите еще доступы Серверной авторизации. Подробнее что это, можно почитать здесь https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/community/faq/#how-do-i-generate-an-htpasswd-file-without-having-apache-tools-installed-3f

Comment: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/401-error/